# App stuck on launch screen and then shows error "No bundle url present"

Tags: firebase, react-native, cocoapods, execution

I have run the project which is created by following
npm install
react-native run-ios
The terminal shows successfully launched app on the simulator.the app also shows the launch screen and it is stuck there for a minute or so and then it shows the error "No bundle url present"

Expected result:
show the first login page screen
acutal result:
app stuck on launch screen and then shows error on the simulator

Comment: This happens to me too, if I go to check the metro bundle it says "error: not opened". Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: how to solve this problem?this app opened earlier but now suddenly it is showing this error.

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: im trying to execute react native project

Answer (score 0):

I've had (and is still having) this problem for a while, only when i'm using a wifi that needs the use of a proxy.

The only "solution" i found, was to add my IP from inside ios->appName->AppDelegete.m into the jscodeLocation variable.

Inside the `#ifdef DEBUG` I changed:

```
    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

to

```
   jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://WRITEYOURIPHERE/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

On Mac I get my ip going:

```
Apple logo at the top left
System preferences
Network
```

and then it will tell you

> You are connect to 'WifiName' with the IP: 1.1.1.1

Just take that number and put it inside the jscodeLocation code i said before instead of WRITEYOURIPHERE:

```
   jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://1.1.1.1/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

This is just a workaround, as it wouldn't let me the server services, failing all the API calls.

Comment: i will try and let u know

Comment: but how will this work when the code is moved to production?

Comment: On production it shouldn't give any problem as the bundle comes with the app itself and will not have this kind of problems

Comment: it didnt solve my problem, still getting no bundle url present error